# Why a TensorFlow Lite model performs great on latency when it is dynamic range quantized, but poorly when it is full integer quantized?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am currently testing the latency of the inference of a CNN transformed with TensorFlow Lite. I am testing two CNNs with the same architecture (I'm testing them on my laptop with Windows OS):

- First model: TensorFlow model optimized with TFLite and with its **weights** quantized (transformed with the Python TFLite API and quantized with tensorflow.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT). It is [dynamic range quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#dynamic_range_quantization).
- Second model: TensorFlow model optimized with TFLite and with its **weights and activations** quantized (transformed with the Python TFLite api and quantized with tensorflow.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT + give a representative dataset). It is [full-integer quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization).

Indeed, the first model (dynamic range quantization) gives very good results time-wise. However, the second model (full-integer quantization) has a very bad performance time-wise (around 10 times slower than the first model).

Why quantizing the activations make the inference process get so slow?

Answer (score 1):

There are lot more activation than weights in a CNN. And activations have to be re-quantized between different layers. Both of these might result in large time in the second case. But remember that the second case should give you better accuracy as well as lower buffer memory requirements as in embedded processors.

Answer (score 1):

It takes 200us for portentha to insert input data to input tensors, invoke CNN model and extract data from model (M7 core).
My CNN model only uses about 20,000 parameters...